# Install taglib on heroku

Tags: heroku, go, taglib

I have a golang app that is using bindings to the C library taglib. When I try to deploy my app, I get the (expected) error that the taglib header file can't be found:

```
-----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
# github.com/wtolson/go-taglib
../github.com/wtolson/go-taglib/taglib.go:6:27: error: taglib/tag_c.h: No such file or     directory
```

So, I attempted to install taglib using apt-get, but that doesn't work.

```
~ $ apt-get install libtag1-dev
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Is anyone aware of how I could install taglib on Heroku?

Comment: If you're not running as root you will probably need to use `sudo` to run `apt-get`.

Comment: `~ $ sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev`
`bash: sudo: command not found` that's interesting..

Comment: Heroku is a platform as a service...I don't believe you can install software in the traditional sense.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo No work around yet?

Comment: Any work around on this?